# Resource could not be resolved

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a error "The resource "ComponentTypeToStringConverter could not be resolved" Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I've got this combo box:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding PcComponent.ComponentTypeName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ComponentTypeToStringConverter}}"/> <!-- HERE I got a error The resource "ComponentTypeToStringConverter could not be resolved -->
           </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:PcConfigurator.Converters">
    <c:ComponentTypeToStringConverter x:Key="ComponentTypeToStringConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Converter (namespace PcConfigurator.Converters):

```
public class ComponentTypeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is ComponentType)) { return null; }

            ComponentType type = (ComponentType)value;

            switch (type)
            {
               //Do something
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Enum value is unknown");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you included the resourcedictionary in your app.xaml and have you build it without code-behind compiler errors? I just assume the namespace is within the same assembly?!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In **design time**. Your resources are not yet compiled and the current `XAML` file that you have where it has the `ComboBox` can't see the `ResourceDictionary`.

Assuming your resources is defined in `App.xaml` then you should have no problems with it when you run it in runtime as it'll be able to find the `key`.

If you want to get rid of the error in **design time** then what you can do is on your `XAML` file where the `ComboBox` lives, you can add the `ResourceDictioanry` so that it'll be able to find it.

Assuming this is a `Window` and you have `ResourceDictionary` that is not defined in the `App.xaml` but as a separate file

```
<Window.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary Source=""/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Amongst the 10+ answers to this question appearing in different forums and formats- that's the only one that actually worked for me. Obvious when explained too. Cheers!